# Extracting Multi Values to Points temporally as well as spatially from NetCDF raster layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extract, arcgis-10.6

I have created a map in ArcGIS 10.6 which includes point data from ARGOS satellite tagged turtles. Each point has a date/time field in a `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` format. I also have a sea surface temperature (SST) as a NetCDF from ERA-Interim with 6-hourly resolution which I have added to the map using 'Make NetCDF Raster Layer'.

Is there a way in ArcGIS to 'Extract Multi Values to Points' temporally as well as spatially from this data?

The time in both datasets will not match exactly so, I need to extract the SST data which is closest to the point time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great solution to this problem. The Marine Geospatial Ecology toolbox has tools to directly extract multi-values to points both spatially and temporally. Find it [here](http://mgel2011-kvm.env.duke.edu/mget/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you break the problem into a couple of steps. First, give the turtle point layer an attribute of "closest sea temp time" that rounds the exact satellite ping to the closest 6 hour time stamp (corresponding with the sea temperature time stamps). Then second extract values to points.

You could do this second step either as Extract Multi Values to Points, ending up with a full range of temperature values per turtle point (and then perhaps needing to discard all the values that don't correspond with your turtle time stamp). Or you could break your data into sections, running Extract Values to Points on each sea temp-turtle time stamp pair (ex. run once each for 0000, 0600, 1200, 1800, etc.). If the later I'd encourage you to write a script to help with this iteration/batch processing of all the time stamps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done as suggested and added an attribute of "closest sea temp time" however, the NetCDF is a single monthly composite which contains 6-hourly SST data so I am not sure how to extract the values from the correct time?